# pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor within a while Loop to wait for GUI update

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

1. I am trying to use pyautogui to check if a screen in my application has loaded by comparing the color of a pixel to a known value.
2. How can I use python and pyautogui to introduce a two second wait to check again if the correct screen has loaded and click a button if the screen load is complete.
3. I tried to use pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor in a while loop to get this to work but keep getting syntax errors.
4. Is there a way to use pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor in a while loop?

   > ## Check if the color at this location is blue (1525, 169)
   >
   > ## Color value - (25, 157, 224)
   >
   > import pyautogui
   >   import time

   While not(pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(1525, 169, (25, 157, 224))):
     time.sleep(5)
   pyautogui.click(1525,169)

Comment: THIS works perfectly for me: 

import pyautogui, time 

while not(pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(300, 300, (255, 0, 0))): 

    pass

print("ready")`